# сайт на github pages долго загружается. (use custom domian)

Tags: github, github-pages, jekyll

Использую github pages в качестве хостинга для блога, 
Блог на jekyll. Прикручен свой домен CNAME: mysite. ru
При первой загрузке очень долгий ответ:
mysite. ru | 200 | document | Other | 4.1 KB |  21.33 s (Initial connection 21.15 s)

1. Если удалить CNAME, то вроде работает все довольно быстро. Как прикрутить свой домен и чтоб быстро работало?
2. Как вообще jekyll на github генерирует папку _site ?
3. Обязательно ли создавать ветку gh-pages?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм. Я уже давно пользуюсь GP с собственным доменом и не сталкивался с таким. Вы вернули CNAME обратно? С тех пор всё те же проблемы?